# Residue of essential singularity with exp

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

I am having troubles finding the residue of f(z) around $z=0$. I am expanding my Laurent series around $z = 0$ but the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is not $0$ as it should be.

$$
f(z) = \frac{z^3e^\frac{1}{z^2}}{z^5+4}
$$

The answer is
$$
Res(f(z),0)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{\frac 1{z^2}}=\sum _{n\ge0}\dfrac {z^{-2n}}{n!}$$

Also $\dfrac 1{z^5+4}=\dfrac 14\dfrac 1{1-(-\frac {z^5}4)}=\dfrac 14\sum _{n\ge0}(-\dfrac {z^5}4)^n$

Putting things together,  one sees that the Laurent series indeed has infinitely many $\dfrac 1z$ terms. Because we have $$\dfrac14(\sum _{n\ge0}\dfrac {z^{-2n+3}}{n!})(\sum _{n\ge0}(\dfrac {-z^5}4)^n)$$.

So every solution to the linear diophantine equation $-2k+3+5l=-1$ gives us a $\dfrac 1z$ term.   The solutions are $(k,l)=(2+5t,2t)$.

So the residue is $$\dfrac 14\sum_{t\ge0}\dfrac 1{(2+5t)!}\dfrac 1{16^t}\gt\dfrac 18$$.

Comment: Yeah. I did this. But for some reason I do not know the answer is 0. Not this sum